# Asp.net mono apache2 multiple sites url not found ubuntu [Solved]

Tags: asp.net, mono, apache2, ubuntu-22.04

Using apache2 with mono.It works with one site but not with more than one when I add it to /etc/mono-server4/asp.net.webapp. where I have

```
<apps>
    <web-application>
        <name>Example</name>
        <vpath>/</vpath>
        <path>/var/www/Example</path>
        <vhost>example.com</vhost>
     </web-application>
</apps>
```

Works until I add another
web-application before /apps where I get URL not found 404 error in both sites in my browser.

Made sure rewrite-mod was installed and verified the config files of both sites restart apache2 and still no change

one config file

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName www.example.com
ServerAlias Example.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/Example
<Directory /var/www/Example/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    SetHandler mono
    DirectoryIndex index.aspx index.html Default.aspx
</Directory>
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/asp.lan-error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/asp.lan-access.log combined
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/Example/DigiCertCA.crt
SSLCertificateFile  /etc/apache2/ssl/Example/example_com.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/Example/example.com.key
```

Note, I have no issues with my own home server. I have many sites there and everything works like a charm. However, I can only have one site on my VPS server go figure.

Comment: https://halfblood.pro/the-end-of-mono/ Microsoft is likely to keep Mono around for a few more months, but you should either go back to Windows or migrate to ASP.NET Core. Staying on Mono means that you need to learn to support yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem in the vphost's of the webapp file, I placed a "www." in front of "example.com", and everything works. I did a lot of trial and error, and finally attained success. After hearing the comment that Mono will be discontinued, I am very anxious. This came from a Microsoft engineer, but I hope that older distributions of Mono will work in the future on other Ubuntu distributions. If worse comes to worst, I can simply migrate to a Windows Server, which I still have. I prefer Ubuntu for this, but oh well, good things don't last.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).